# change link in the table.html.twig

Tags: drupal

I'm working with drupal 8. I enable debug and I found `[
<!-- BEGIN OUTPUT from ‘core/themes/stable/templates/dataset/table.html.twig’ --> ]` then I overwrite table.html.twig in my theme folder. Now the  tag include a link that I want to add [/edit] to it. to make user navigate to the edit page. the following code is from the core file.

```
    <tbody>
      {% for row in rows %}
        <tr{{ row.attributes }}>
          {% for cell in row.cells %}
            <{{ cell.tag }}{{ cell.attributes }}>
              {{- cell.content -}}
            </{{ cell.tag }}>
          {% endfor %}
        </tr>
      {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
```

I try to create preprocess function

```
/* this preprocess method is to add variables to table.html.twig*/
function mytheme_preprocess_table(&$variables) {
  print_r(array_keys($variables));
  $variables['output'] = "add your custom";
  $variables['hello'] = 'world';
}
```

but I don't know how to access [cell.content] in order to add [/edit]

How is the table generated? it's from the code. Where is the table displayed? in `https://example.com/ar/webform/companies_form/submissions/` What is the path of "edit web form page"? `webform/companies_form/submissions/3119/edit` Have you debugged the template to see what variables are available in the template? yes,

```
Array
(
    [0] =&gt; header
    [1] =&gt; rows
    [2] =&gt; attributes
    [3] =&gt; sticky
    [4] =&gt; responsive
    [5] =&gt; empty
    [6] =&gt; footer
    [7] =&gt; caption
    [8] =&gt; colgroups
    [9] =&gt; theme_hook_original
    [10] =&gt; title_attributes
    [11] =&gt; content_attributes
    [12] =&gt; title_prefix
    [13] =&gt; title_suffix
    [14] =&gt; db_is_active
    [15] =&gt; is_admin
    [16] =&gt; logged_in
    [17] =&gt; user
    [18] =&gt; directory
    [19] =&gt; header_columns
    [20] =&gt; no_striping
    [21] =&gt; #cache
)
```

Comment: What have you tried already? How is the table generated? Where is the table displayed?  What is the path of "edit web form page"? Have you debugged the template to see what variables are available in the template? You will need to add some more detail to the question if you expect a good answer.

Comment: @2pha please check my updated question.

Comment: It seems you are talking about a webform submissions table (generated by a view in the webform module), you can probably just **edit the view** (rather than overriding templates etc.). Though I would have thought that view already had an edit link for each submission.

Comment: @2pha I check the views. but I didn't find view for webform submissions table